# Should container get value from props?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have an app structure like this with redux:

```
app
|-router
| — dashboard container
| — — dashboard component
| — setting container
| — — setting component
```

Consider the two containers, if I need to get translation text from the store which way should I used?

(1) Connect to redux store on router and pass down to containers by props

(2) Each of the container connect to redux store individually

Comment: using connect is better as it gives you performance gains and is cleaner

Answer (score 2):

As Dan Abramov, author of redux says in this issue

Both approaches of passing props down to children or connecting them to the store are appropriate, however having nested connect() components is actually going to give you more performance. The downside is they're slightly more coupled to the application and slightly harder to test, but that may not be a big issue.

He has also articulated a nice rule of thumb to follow on reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4azg7q/using_redux_how_do_you_handle_subcomponents_of_a/

I do it this way:

Start by using one container and several presentational components
As presentational component tree grows, “middle” components start to pass too many props down
At this point, I wrap some leaf components into containers so that “middle” components don’t need to accept and pass down props that are completely unrelated to them
Repeat
He has even tweeted regarding this:

Try to keep your presentation components separate. Create container components by connecting them when it’s convenient.Whenever you feel like you’re duplicating code in parent components to provide data for same kinds of children, time to extract a container.

So in simple words:

You can use connect() at any level. Doing so makes the component smart, since it knows where its props come from. A dumb component just has props, and they could come from anywhere. A smart component is coupled to redux; a dumb component is not.

Answer (score 0):

if the translations are dispatched from router then use connect if they are not fetched or updated by dispatching an action and will never update passing them is better.